# How to replicate different tables to different databases in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

I have `Database1` on `server1` and `Database2`,`Database3` on `server2`. `Database1` has two tables `T1`, `T2`. I want to replicate `T1 on Database2` and `T2 on Database3`.

How can I accomplish it?

I googled but only found examples where replication was performed to only one DB.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the replication on `Database2` to only `T1` and on `Database3` to only `T2`, using the `--replicate-do-table=name` option:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table

Comment: Invalid links..